# syntax issue with print on python 3

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

```
def main():

    birthRate = (60 / 7)    # Births in a minute
    deathRate = (60 / 13)       # Deaths in a minute
    immigrantRate = (60 / 45)       # New immigrants in a minute
    minutesInaYear = (24 * 60 * 365)        # The number of seconds in a years
    minutesInaLeapYear = (24 * 60 * 366)
    currentPopulation = 312032486
    totalRate = (birthRate - deathRate + immigrantRate)

    populationIncreaseInaYear = (totalRate * minutesInaYear) # Calculates the increase in population after a year

    populationInaYear = (currentPopulation + populationIncreaseInaYear) # Total population after a year

    populationInTwoYears = (currentPopulation + (2 * populationIncreaseInaYear))

    populationInThreeYears = (currentPopulation + (3 * populationIncreaseInaYear))

    populationInFourYears = (currentPopulation + (4 * populationIncreaseInaYear))

    populationInFiveYears = ((populationInFourYears +  (totalRate * minutesInaYear))

    print("The population after one year is: " , populationInaYear)  '''PRINT FUNCTION DOESN'T WORK?'''

    print("The population after two years is: " , populationInTwoYears)
    print("The population after three years is: " , populationInThreeYears)
    print("The population after four years is: " , populationInFourYears)
    print("The population after five years is: " , populationInFiveYears)

main()
```

Why isn't print working? Even when I replace everything in the parenthesis with a number it says there is a syntax error at the "t" in print. What's going on?

Comment: Please verify your post is correctly formatted before posting. Also, at what line is this error occurring? What is the precise message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an unmatched open parenthesis in the line:

```
populationInFiveYears = ((populationInFourYears +  (totalRate * minutesInaYear))
```

either remove the first open parenthesis '(' after the '=', or add another close parenthesis ')' at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra "(" at the begining of your `populationInFiveYears` line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the round bracket from the previous line. The right code is :

```
populationInFiveYears = ((populationInFourYears +  (totalRate * minutesInaYear)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As others said, you missing a parenthesis `)` at the end of

```
populationInFiveYears = ((populationInFourYears +  (totalRate * minutesInaYear))
```

But you have one more mistake:

```
print("The population after one year is: " , populationInaYear)  '''PRINT FUNCTION DOESN'T WORK?'''
```

If you want to comment it use `#`

```
print("The population after one year is: " , populationInaYear)  # PRINT FUNCTION DOESN'T WORK?
```

`'''` isn't for comments. Its a multi-line string...

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the error message, there is a caret(^) pointing to the token the parser is claiming as a syntax error.

```
  File "C:\test.py", line 22
    print("The population after one year is: " , populationInaYear)  '''PRINT FUNCTION DOESN'T WORK?'''
        ^
```

It is pointing to the `print` token.  That indicates the parser didn't expect `print` as the next token.  Since that is the first token on the line, go back to the previous line and look for the problem there.  As others have pointed out, you have mismatched parameters on the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python to do calculations doesn't require brackets, Python also automatically follows the orders of operations, so:

```
birthRate = 60 / 7    
deathRate = 60 / 13
immigrantRate = 60 / 45
minutesInaYear = 24 * 60 * 365
minutesInaLeapYear = 24 * 60 * 366
currentPopulation = 312032486
totalRate = birthRate - deathRate + immigrantRate

populationIncreaseInaYear = totalRate * minutesInaYear

populationInaYear = currentPopulation + populationIncreaseInaYear

populationInTwoYears = currentPopulation + 2 * populationIncreaseInaYear

populationInThreeYears = currentPopulation + 3 * populationIncreaseInaYear

populationInFourYears = currentPopulation + 4 * populationIncreaseInaYear

populationInFiveYears = populationInFourYears +  totalRate * minutesInaYear 
#you got an extra bracket after '=' which caused the error

print("The population after one year is: " , populationInaYear)  
print("The population after two years is: " , populationInTwoYears)
print("The population after three years is: " , populationInThreeYears)
print("The population after four years is: " , populationInFourYears)
print("The population after five years is: " , populationInFiveYears)
```

and I would also recommend doing this:

```
print("The population after one year is: %i" %populationInaYear)  
print("The population after two years is: %i" %populationInTwoYears)
print("The population after three years is: %i" %populationInThreeYears)
print("The population after four years is: %i" %populationInFourYears)
print("The population after five years is: %i" %populationInFiveYears)
```

which converts all the float to int when printing. Since the total population couldn't be a float since there's no such thing as 0.293283 person.